# Get descendants of page in Grav admin

Tags: php, grav

In a grav theme plugin, I want to provide a method to fill a select input field in a page blueprint with some other page's routes:

```yaml
video_route:
  type: select
  data-options@: '\Grav\Theme\MyTheme::videoRoutes'
```

Those pages must be descendants of another specific page, called 'videos', here. My theme plugin method looks like this:

```php
public static function videoRoutes() : array
{
    $pages = new Pages(Grav::instance());
    $pages->init();
    $collection = $pages->getCollection(['items' => ['@page.descendants' => '/videos']]);
    [...]
}
```

Inside the *Grav\Common\Page\Pages::getCollection()* method, the 'videos' object is found and instanciated, and the format of the params array seems also correct. But the resulting collection is empty. What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Would you mind providing a bit more info? What is the higher goal you're trying to achieve? What is "admin function". Where and when is your code running?

Comment: @passerby - I added some context to my question, hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public static function videoRoutes()
{
    $grav = Grav::instance();
    $grav['admin']->enablePages();   
    $pages = $grav['pages'];

    $collection = $pages->getCollection(['items' => ['@page.descendants' => '/videos']]);
    [...]
}
```

`Admin->enablePages()` calls `Pages->enablePages()`. According the [docs](https://learn.getgrav.org/17/api#class-grav-common-page-pages):

> public    enablePages() : void
>
> Method used in admin to later load frontend pages.

Please be advised that if you use above code inside a theme installed from Grav's theme repo, you will lose all changes on next update of the theme. You should in that case create an [inherited theme](https://learn.getgrav.org/17/themes/customization#theme-inheritance), or create a plugin.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I already tried to call `enablePages()` directly on the `Pages` object, without success. The important thing is that you pull the `Pages` object from the `Grav` container. `$pages = new Pages($grav);` doesn't work here.